# Cordova not install on OSX Yosemite

Tags: ios, node.js, macos, npm

I'm trying to install Apache Cordova on Yosemite, but when I write the following command on terminal:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

...it stay only loading for hours and nothing happens. I already tried to install the older versions, but doesn't work too.

I have a xcode, command-line and ios sdk installed. All requirements to install cordova.

Comment: Did you install npm? And what exactly does your terminal say?

Comment: Yes, I installed. It says nothing. It is just loading. I already left for one night and nothing happened. I think the biggest problem is that it shows no error.

Comment: Can you please upload a screenshot?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/gdJcgMK.png?1 Just this for hours...

Comment: look at this: https://github.com/yaronn/blessed-contrib/issues/4

Comment: How this topic can help me? I need to install from source?

Comment: How did you install node.js?

Comment: I downloaded and installed the package. I discovered that the problem is with the npm, I can not install anything with it.

Comment: I fix my problem.. I just added the node and npm in $PATH.